# How do I create links in Confluence footer

Tags: html, hyperlink, footer, confluence

Using Confluence 5.7 and I'd like to put links in my footer. When I try, using code that works in the body, this is what appears on the rendered page:

© Copyright 1990-2016 xxxxx, a division of xxxx, Inc. All rights reserved.
Any documentation bugs or feature requests should be reported - <a href="lwfb://mode=bug,area=Documentation,lockarea">)Bug</a> <a href="lwfb://mode=feature,area=Documentation,lockarea">Feature</a>

Obviously, starting a link with "lwfb://" is not the regular "http://" but a standard link results in the same output.

I hope I've explained the issue succinctly enough. Any advice will be gratefully received.

B

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else encounters this problem, the answer is to use Shortcut links in the Confluence General Configuration pane. You create a key, followed by the full URI you want to use and the Alias you want to appear on the page. To use the shortcut in a page (or in the footer as I want to here) add [@xxx] to the page, [@lwfb-bug] for my example here.

B

PS. Anchors don't seem to work in these links